# How is .ascx.cs file storing the data entered in the text boxes of .ascx

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I'm complete newbie for .Net development so I apologize for such silly question before hand.

I'm trying to understand & learn .Net Development so I'm looking at this project which has text boxes in .ascx file and I believe the code behind of it is supposed to save the data entered in those text boxes to a database. But I'm not understanding how & where is that data getting stored or going. Basically the code behind file looks something like this,

```
public partial class registration : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblDisclosure;

        private ResourceManager rm = null;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           lblFirstName.Text = rm.GetString("FirstName");
        }                            
    }
```

Can someone please help me with this? Or give me some resources to read on.

Comment: The value of rm.GetString("FirstName") will be displayed in a label (I'm guessing it's a label) in the ascx control. The ID of the label is lblFirstName. Do you see such a label on the ascx page?

Comment: The code you posted does not show any interaction with any database.

Answer (score 1):

Generally connection settings to the database can be found in Web.config.

In an ASP.Net WebForms project like this, the code that captures the saved data is probably in the .aspx.cs codebehind of the page this .ascx happens to be used in. What this code looks like varies widely depending on how they're talking to the database - they might be using plain SQL, LINQ to SQL, Entity Framework, NHibernate, something of their own creation, who knows - but I bet it starts in the codebehind either way.

Usually data like this is just posted back in a plain form submit, so it's common to see something like

```
if (IsPostBack....
```

in the codebehind.

Comment: Thanks Chris. For some weird reason I can't find the .aspx page at all. By the way, this application is deployed in Sharepoint.

Yes, I found the data connection string in the web.config file but I'm not understanding how they are actually writing it into the database

Comment: So are you developing a WebPart?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, I'm not developing. I'm just trying to understand the application

Comment: Unfortunately the number of ways to redirect the URL in ASP.Net are pretty numerous - you could just do a Find Files on the whole Project looking for the .ascx name.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial gives an example of what you're trying to accomplish: [Working with Databases in ASP.NET 2.0 and Visual Studio 2005](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131040/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/110905-1.aspx)

Although it's old, it talks about how to set up a database connection through a `SqlDataSource`, as well as how to bind it to `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` statements. Then, it describes how to get data from the page into the database through control binding.

That having been said, I would recommend learning ASP.NET MVC instead. You will gain the same capability to leverage the .NET framework without having to learn the ASP.NET page lifecycle, which is not trivial.

Comment: Thanks Neo.

With my limited knowledge, I feel the data being typed into the text boxes is written to a hash table and then picked up by a web service. So I was wondering if there is a way to identify which service is being used by looking at the code behind

Comment: Not from what you've shared thus far. I tagged this question with "sharepoint" from your other comment, which should get you some specific help. The article I quoted won't be of use here.